# Repeated pop-up from "Interactive Services Detection" after installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, installation

I've installed Visual Studio 2010 with Service Pack 1 on Windows 7. I am logged on as an administrator and running the application using the "Run as administrator" option in the shortcut to `devenv.exe`.

Now I get a message periodically, even when the application does not seem to be running (i.e., can't find any evidence of it running even as a service or in the process list in Task Manager).

It starts with a pop-up titled "Interactive Services Detection" with the message:

> A programming running on this computer is trying to display a message.

When I click "View the message" I see the following:

> A device or program has requested attention. Device or application:
>   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.
>   Message title: Microsoft Visual Studio.

I also see this message:

> The Application Data folder for Visual Studio could not be created.

A similar installation on another similarly configured computer does not have this problem.

Are there any additional steps which need to be taken to get Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to work correctly on Windows 7?